# Как получить чистый исполняемый двоичный файл на Linux?

Tags: gcc, linux

Например, есть C код:

```
static int add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Как скомпилировать этот код в бинарный файл, который будет исполняться с начала файла байт за байтом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать утилиту `objcopy` с флагом `-O binary` из GNU binutils.

```
$ gcc -c sample.c
$ objcopy -O binary sample.o sample.bin
```